# Adding methods to POCO classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, poco

I have the following setup: MVC > Services > Repositories. Now I want to allow users to be able to add a Note to a Document. Only Users associated with the Document (either as owners or reviewers) can add Notes so in my NoteService I do the following to ensure the User has permission on the selected Document:

```
public Note GetNewNote(int documentID)
    {
        if (!userHasAccess(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name))
            throw new BusinessLogicException();

        // Other stuff here...
    }
```

My question is, where should I define the userHasAccess method? It makes no sense in the NoteService as it is checking on a Document. I could define it in the DocumentService but will then NoteService will need access to this which seems to be introducing more coupling.

To me it makes more sense to define it on the Document POCO itself and then call document.userHasAccess(...). Would this be good practice or should a domain POCO be limited to simple properties? I am concerned that this is really part of the validation and that by placing the method in the POCO I am seperating the validation between Service and POCO.

What I am trying to ensure is that my application is easy to maintain and test. Any suggestions on how I should tackle this would be most appreciated!

Comment: What kind of check do userHasAccess do? Code Access Security might work for you.

Comment: It just checks that the User is either in Document.Owners or Document.Reviewers - these are many to many relationships between Document and Person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where should I define the userHasAccess method?

It makes sense to be consistent with the rest of the design, while I don't know the full design I can at least say that a method called UserHasAccess() on the POCO itself makes sense.

> Should a domain POCO be limited to simple properties?

No, a domain POCO should contain logic (especially validation logic) related to the object. Otherwise, it ends up being an [object with no behaviour](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) - something you should definitely avoid.

However, don't get confused between a domain (business) object and a view object, which will typically contain little logic.

> You are concerned that you are separating the validation between
>   Service and POCO.

I'd put validation in the POCO, and cross-domain logic in the services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link. Just to push this on a little futher, what kind of validations tend to go in POCOs? Is it things like in my example, simple methods which are then called by a Service? So a Service can call the ones it needs to determine if a validation exception (or whatever) should be thrown to the controller? Or should there be some sort of validate method on my POCOs?

Comment: I would have a validate method on each POCO - it makes sense that a POCO knows if it's valid. Your example is a bit different though and makes sense being a method itself.

Comment: The validate method idea confuses me because different Service methods will require different things in order to call the POCO valid. With my example, userHasAccess is just asking the POCO if we can do something whereas a validate method in my mind would do the checks like "username must be unique". Does this not start to tie the POCO in with EntityFramework?

Comment: The problem with a single validate method on a POCO is that you could have more than one action you want to validate. Is it valid to insert to database? Is it valid to modify? If you start adding multiple validate methods then your POCO starts having multiple responsibilities. I prefer to have the validation logic in separate classes.

Comment: @epignosisx - the validate method will certainly have more than one action - e.g. does the Credit Card have a valid start/expiry date, a valid card number for the type of card... These would all be in a single validate method that returns multiple validation messages.

Comment: @james - your method might require another POCO as a parameter. How that parameter got populated should be irrelevant. The whole point of a POCO is that the data access code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Any domain entity can contain validation methods as well.

Comment: Is this good practice though? I dont want to start adding these seemingly simple methods to my POCO classes only to find later on that it becomes difficult to maintain/test. It would be nice to keep all validation in one section - with the above example I _could_ just check if the User is in document.Owners and then if in document.Reviewers but I will need to repeat this logic again and again so it needs to be its own method.

Comment: James , as Joe mentioned in his answer, you can put validation in the POCO, and cross-domain logic in the services.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are following Domain Model Pattern then you can add attributes with behaviors.
   Check this by [Martin fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html)
2. If you are following Table Module pattern then add behaviors in BLL class and attributes in POCO
   check this as well by [Martin fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html)